# Defining a "Belongs to"-relationship in FluentAPI - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have 2 tables like following:
[Table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NzhC.png)

And I want to become these things in an Entity Framework **Core** project:

1. A **User** doesn't have to be a **TeamMember**
2. Every **TeamMember** is a **User**
3. When I delete a **User** the **TeamMember** has to get deleted
4. When I delete a **TeamMember** the **User** must stay untouched
5. The *Primary Key* of the **TeamMember** is the *Foreign Key* to the **User** table

Anybody who can explain me how to become this with the FluentAPI methods, I just can't seem to find the correct way because my DeleteBehaviour doesn't seem to work.

Comment: is it one(user) to one(teamMember)? or one(user) to many(teamMember)?

Comment: Sounds like standard one-to-one relationship with User being the principal and TeamMember being the dependent. We need the classes in question (especially the navigation properties) in order to give you the fluent configuration.

Comment: @GabrielLlorico Should be one-to-one - see the bullet #5 (shared PK association).

Comment: @IvanStoev added an answer on it, just saw it late

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will delete the `TeamMember` on delete of `User`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TeamMember>()
        .HasOne(b => b.User)
        .WithOne(TeamMember)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```